# How does mathematica calculate CovarianceMatrix in NonLinearModelFit

Tags: matrix, fitting, nonlinear

I have read ["StatisticalModelAnalysis-Tutorial"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StatisticalModelAnalysis.html#144989606) and try to follow the definitions to calculate the ParameterError step-by-step. What I figured out is `ParameterErrors` in `nlm["ParameterTable"]` is calculated from diagonal entries of Covariance Matrix `Sqrt[nlm["CovarianceMatrix"]] // Diagonal`. From link above the definition of `CovarianceMatrix` is as follows:

> "The matrix is sigma^2 (X^T W X)^(-1), where sigma^2 is the variance estimate, X is the design matrix for the linear approximation to the model, and W is the diagonal matrix of weights."

This is the Function, data and weights I putted in `NonLinearModelFit`:

```
f = Function[{a, b, x}, b + a*x];
data = {{6., 21.}, {8., 31.}, {9., 39.}};
weights = {1., 1., 1.};
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, f[a, b, x], {a, b}, x, Weights -> weights, VarianceEstimatorFunction -> (1 &)];
```

The "DesignMatrix" `X` I think is produced from `y_i` estimates:

```
para = a /. nlm["BestFitParameters"];
parb = b /. nlm["BestFitParameters"];
yestimates = f[para, parb, data[[All, 1]]]
designmatrix = DesignMatrix[data, f[para, parb, x], x];
designmatrix // MatrixForm
```

Now one point I do not understand. What is `sigma^2` ? I thought it could be EstimatedVariance:

```
varianceestimate = nlm["EstimatedVariance"];
```

Which in my case gives 1 because I did `VarianceEstimatorFunction-> (1&)` in nlm.
The "Matrix of weights" W I thought to be:

```
matrixofweights = DiagonalMatrix[weights];
```

And now calculate the Covariance Matrix from definiton above:

```
varianceestimate*Inverse[Transpose[designmatrix].matrixofweights.designmatrix]//MatrixForm
```

> `out:{{6.08061, -0.189471},{-0.189471, 0.00624628}}`

And comparison with original CovarianceMarix don't give the same result:

```
nlm["CovarianceMatrix"] // MatrixForm
```

> `out: {{0.214286, -1.64286}, {-1.64286, 12.9286}}`

Can somebody help?

Edit: By the way, at least there is no factor between these different  results. so my mistake could not only due to `sigma^2`.

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing `Covariance` and `Variance`? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance

Comment: Parameters standard error is a standard deviation which is calculated from `Sqrt[nlm["CovarianceMatrix"]] // Diagonal` in this case I'm sure... I'am not sure in expression "variance estimate"

Comment: So, now I nearly figured out myself. Should I edit the entry above or just do a comment? Sorry, for asking then solve it ... but I tried over hours don't come to a result..

Comment: Nothing wrong with that! Feel free to post an answer down the page to your own question. This sort of question doesn't often get an answer from the community because it's more statistics oriented than *Mathematica* oriented. I just hope next time others can be of more use.

Comment: so, where should or can I ask this kind of questions?

Comment: You still can ask these questions here; it just happens that the people very knowledgeable in statistical matters are not present for now. One usually waits a bit for questions that are sufficiently sophisticated, but you are lucky you figured it out yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just a note:  it has been called the design matrix for linear models long before even I was born.  A statistics class would help with the terminology.

However, in a nonlinear setting it turns out to be a slightly more complicated item that still results in the usual design matrix when the model is linear.

I'm going to ignore the issue of weighting because it's all about what **X** is for a nonlinear model.  Below is shown an example of a nonlinear model using `NonlinearModelFit` and a brute force maximum likelihood method to show the underlying calculations.

```
 (* Generate data from a nonlinear model *)
 SeedRandom[12472475];
 x = Flatten[Table[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {i, 5}]];
 n = Length[x];
 aa = 1;
 bb = 0.5;
 σσ = 0.05;
 y = aa Exp[-bb x] + 
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, σσ], n];

 (* Fit with NonlinearModelFit *)
 nlm = NonlinearModelFit[Transpose[{x, y}], a Exp[-b z], {a, b}, z];

 (* Fit with brute force method *)
 (* Get log of the likelihood *)
 logL = LogLikelihood[NormalDistribution[0, σ], y - a Exp[-b x]];
 (* Find maximum likelihood estimates of parameters *)
 mle = FindMaximum[{logL, σ > 0}, {{a, 1}, {b, 0.5}, {σ, 0.05}}];

 (* Now approximate and then estimate the covariance matrix *)
 (* Note the definition of X, the design matrix *)
 X = D[a Exp[-b x], {{a, b}}];
 (* Multiplication by n/(n-2) is to use the unbiased estimate of σ^2 *)
 (* n - 2 is really sample size minus number of parameters *)
 cov = (n/(n - 2)) (σ^2 Inverse[Transpose[X]. X]) /. mle[[2]];


 (* Parameter estimates *)
 nlm["BestFitParameters"]
 (* {a -> 0.9842981255137611,b -> 0.5023511174255275} *)
 mle[[2]][[1 ;; 2]]
 (* {a -> 0.9842981255018496,b -> 0.50235111740454} *)

 (* Estimates of covariance matrix *)
 nlm["CovarianceMatrix"]
 (* {{0.00034959357568038475,0.00016592363407431294},
    {0.00016592363407431294,0.0002923502562857745}} *)
 cov
 (* {{0.00034959357700581665,0.0001659236346998225},
     {0.0001659236346998225,0.00029235025737224096}} *)

 Rationalize[cov/nlm["CovarianceMatrix"], 0.00001]
 (* Estimates of σ^2 *)
 nlm["EstimatedVariance"]
(* 0.002014630678417603 *)
((n/(n - 2)) σ^2 /. mle[[2, 3]])
(* 0.0020146306860807216 *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That help me to understand!

Answer (score 2):

I will answer myself half the way. So I misunderstood the design matrix, it should be `DesignMatrix` OF X. ok that's stupid because it is called X. design matrix has the form {{1.,Xestimate_1} ,{1.,Xestimate_2},...}. The following code will produce the same matrix as `nlm["CovarianceMatrix"]` does. BUT just for linear models `b + a*x`. So there is still a open question. :-)

```
f = Function[{a, b, x}, b + a*x];
data = {{6., 21.}, {8., 31.}, {9., 39.}};
weights = {0.5, 4.5, 0.1};
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, f[a, b, x], {a, b}, x,Weights -> weights, VarianceEstimatorFunction -> Automatic]
yestimates = Table[nlm[data[[i, 1]]], {i, Length[data]}]
xestimates = Flatten[Table[x /. Solve[nlm[x] == yestimates[[i]]], {i,Length[data]}]]
xdesignmatrix = Table[{1., xestimates[[i]]}, {i, Length[data]}];
varianceestimate = nlm["EstimatedVariance"];
matrixofweights = DiagonalMatrix[weights];
varianceestimate*Inverse[Transpose[xdesignmatrix].matrixofweights.xdesignmatrix]
% // MatrixForm
nlm["CovarianceMatrix"] // MatrixForm
```

> output: {{25.9587, -3.29752}, {-3.29752, 0.421488}}